# Mongo DB - Why my Users.findOne is Undefined?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm working on Meteor, trying to find some values from Mongodb collection.
here is the code:

```js
      var sameLogins = Users.findOne({login: 'a'});
      console.log(sameLogins);
```

But it's returning and "undefined".
But record exists in collection:
[image]

So, can anybody tell what I'm missing?

Also, in mongo console - everything is working fine:
[image]

I was looking in Publish/Subsribe stuff, but i'm using autopublish module yet.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You need to provide a callback.

Comment: If you are using the user collection from the package `account-base` then you can access it with `Meteor.users` and not `Users`. `Meteor.users.findOne({login: 'a'});`

Comment: @evolutionxbox how could I make it?

Comment: You should show the code where you're initializing your `Users` as well, otherwise it's unclear what is it.

Comment: @Styx they are: `export const Users = Meteor.users;`

Comment: @OlegSmirnoff did you try to use `Meteor.users.findOne(...)` instead of `Users.findOne(...)`?

Comment: @Styx yes, I partly understand what's the problem, there are no callback, but I'm new at programming, so I don't understand it a bit :D

Comment: @OlegSmirnoff I don't think your problem is related with callbacks. In Meteor, DB calls are synchronous. Have a look at the [`findOne` documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-findOne).

Comment: @OlegSmirnoff I suspect you and your Meteor app are using different Mongo DBs, that's why you're getting different results. Could you confirm/deny that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153156/discussion-between-oleg-smirnoff-and-styx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will leave the answer for this issue for new users having the same problem.

If you're using `autopublish` package then you should be aware that it's publishing the result of `.find()` for every collection.

But, `Meteor.users.find()`, be default, will return only `_id` and `profile` fields, so documents in your `Meteor.users` *client* collection will have these two fields only.

The most easy workaround for this would be to create your own publication (`allUsers`, for example) and in it to return those fields you need:

**Server:**

```
Meteor.publish('allUsers', () => {
  // check for Meteor.userId() is omitted, put it here, if needed
  return Meteor.users.find({}, { fields: { ... } });
});
```

Don't forget to subscribe to it:

**Client:**

```
Meteor.subscribe('allUsers');
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for Meteor:
Right now you are storing a [cursor](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) in your variable `sameLogins`. In order to retrieve the results you want, you must actually execute this query by either calling `fetch()`. What is returned from findOne without fetch is essentially an object that you could use to iterate over and find mongoDB documents - (called a collection cursor). The cursor is not your result itself.

Calling [fetch](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-fetch) would like something like:

```
Users.findOne({login: 'a'}).fetch()
```

Comment: Why do you think the `mongoose` is used? There is no such thing mentioned, neither in tags nor in the question itself.

Comment: @pneedle Anyway, you can join chat, to help with this issue  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153156/discussion-between-oleg-smirnoff-and-styx